# What is the time synchronization precision in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: time

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with synchronized time:

```
$ timedatectl
  Local time: Fri 2018-12-21 23:00:50 UTC
  Universal time: Fri 2018-12-21 23:00:50 UTC
   RTC time: Fri 2018-12-21 23:00:51
   Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
   Network time on: yes
   NTP synchronized: yes
   RTC in local TZ: no
```

but it is not clear what is the time synchronization precision Ubuntu guarantee and is it possible to determine the difference between the local time and NTP server time?

For example, in Windows 10 this can be done with the following command:

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:ru.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:5

Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 12/22/2018 1:42:24 AM.
01:42:24, -00.6062814s
01:42:26, -00.6051949s
01:42:28, -00.6055661s
01:42:31, -00.6038737s
01:42:33, -00.6050809s
```

is there something like this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Try `timedatectl timesync-status` for precision information.

Comment: @user535733 I am getting 'Unknown operation timesync-status'. I have 16.04, but not 18.04

Comment: Ah, it must have improved from 16.04 to 18.04, sorry.

Comment: There's a useful website called https://time.is/ that shows you the current exact time and compares your local clock difference.

Comment: @ByteCommander I do not have UI, only command line.

Comment: I was able to check the time sync accuracy with crony, see https://developernote.com/2018/12/setting-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If you install chrony, then you're not using the default systemd provided NTP service...

Comment: @user535733 I have 18.04 and there still no `timesync-status`... Maybe you had 18.10?

Comment: Perhaps. That was a long time ago now.

Comment: @user535733 On Ubuntu 16.04 I am getting "Unknown operation timesync-status".